# Proccessing data from line in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have data format below

```
int : int \t string
```

for example,

```
11:11     long long long description.
```

I use

```
sscanf(line, "%d:%d\t%s\n", &num1, &num2, &description)
```

but it only cuts the first word from the description.
How should I proceed the data from line to receive all characters in description with spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format specification **%s** will read a string, until a whitespace character is found. If you want to read all characters up to **\n** you can do **%[^\n]**. That says read characters as long as the character is not in the set that contains the newline character. Note that the trailing \n is not read by it. So the final solution would be:

```
sscanf(line, "%d:%d\t%[^\n]", &num1, &num2, description);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sscanf(line, "%d : %d\t%s\n", &num1, &num2, &description)
```

Comment: yes. i meant exactly this. i just it posted with this stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

since your format is pretty simple I would if I were you just loop over the string and cutting it at suitable places with \0 since you
know how many parts there should be.

often the simpler the design, the more foolproof it is